# Undefined reference C++

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I have a file called Student.h which have the static integers in this way:

```
    class Student
{
public:
    static int _avrA,_avrB,_avrC,_avrD;
};
```

and I have university.h that inherits Student.h .
On the implementation of University.cpp , one of the functions returns:

```
return (_grade_average*(Student::_avrA/Student::_avrB))+7;
```

and the compiler writes:

> undefined reference to Student::_avrA.

Do you know why it happens?

Comment: variable names with underscore are reserved, you cannot use them

Comment: What do you mean by “I have university.h that inherits Student.h”? One file cannot *inherit* another file. Did you mean “include”?

Comment: `university.cpp` includes `university.h`, right? also I'm assuming by inherit you mean `university.h` includes `student.h`

Comment: @Tony Not true. Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by lower-case letters are only reserved in the global namespace.

Comment: @Tony yeah, people have been using identifiers starting with `_` to signify member variables (to keep them apart from getter functions with the same name) since the dawn of time. Doesn't mean it's ok, but it should tell you something :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have *declared* those variables, but you haven't *defined* them. So you've told the compiler "Somewhere I'm going to have a variable with this name, so when I use that name, don't wig out about undefined variables until you've looked everywhere for its definition."<sup>1</sup>

In a `.cpp` file, add the definitions:

```
int Student::_avrA; // _avrA is now 0*
int Student::_avrB = 1; // _avrB is now 1
int Student::_avrC = 0; // _avrC is now 0
int Student::_avrD = 2; // _avrD is now 2
```

Don't do this in a `.h` file because if you include it twice in two different `.cpp` files, you'll get multiple definition errors because the linker will see more than one file trying to  create a variable named `Student::_avrA`, `Student::_avbB`, etc. and according to the [One Definition to Rule Them All](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) rule, that's illegal.

<sup>1</sup> Much like a function prototype. In your code, it's as if you have a function prototype but no body.

<sup>*</sup> Because "Static integer members of classes are guaranteed to be initialised to zero in the absence of an explicit initialiser." (TonyK)

Comment: ints should have some value even if they have not been set one - that value is undefined or implementation specific, but the reference to the variable should not be undefined. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jukka I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean that you don't have to have the `= 0`, you're correct, but I was assuming he doesn't want his variables to have unpredictable values.

Comment: @Jukka The variable must exist in order to have any value (set or not). The OP only declared the variables, but did not create them anywhere.

Comment: @Seth: Static integer members of classes are guaranteed to be initialised to zero in the absence of an explicit initialiser. So `= 0` really is superfluous.

Comment: @TonyK it was really to show that you could assign it some value there. I'll change it to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

You have to *define* the static data members as well as declaring them. In your implementation Student.cpp, add the following definitions:

```
int Student::_avrA;
int Student::_avrB;
int Student::_avrC;
int Student::_avrD;
```